# How to simulate Plug/Unplug of a USB in C#

Tags: usb

I am new in Programming and I think I must go deep in programming.
We have a device connected to a USB port and during reboot enters in Low Power Mode, and It is unable to wake up after that, except if it is unplugged and plugged again.
I have tried devcon, but the device was not recognized correctly by windows and thus it did not work.
So far I have managed to make it work using a relay in the Power Line and this is what I want to simulate programaticaly if possible.
I know it is drivers but I have already contacted the company and they say it is a problem with their drivers but do not have a date for the fix and our deadline is coming really fast.
I have searched in the Internet and the only way to achieve it is by IOCTL_USB_HUB_CYCLE_PORT but I have no idea how to start.. 
Any help would be really valuable. In some forums they have made an effort but I have not find any example that works so far so if you please give me some hints with code would be really good for me.
ripping the USB cable and altering the shielding is not the best option that is why I am asking for help.
If you could please provide me with some extra info.
Thank you very much